# How to pass parameters to a get request

Tags: javascript, get, fetch

I know we can pass parameters through the URL, but I am working on this project and the API provided via documentation wants a call to the GET like this:

```
GET http://server.com/ppe/xxfigure
{
"token":"string",
"lang":"string"
}
```

How do I execute the fetch function here?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer!

If I am using the fetch function, you have to include the parameters in the URL and execute the fetch operation (GET). On the server this can be called using the req.query. e.g

```
fetch(`http://server.com/ppe/xxfigure?token=${token}&lang=${lang}`,{
method:"GET",
})
```

However, if I am using the axios package for the GET operation, the code can be:

```
 axios.get("http://server.com/ppe/xxfigure",{
  params:{
   {
    "token":"string",
    "lang":"string"
   }
  }
})
```

With axios, on the server, req.query will retrieve the information in the params block.
Thanks to all that contributed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can set it as headers:

```
fetch('insertUrlHere', {
    headers: {
      "token":"tokenValue",
      "lang":"langValue"  
    }
});
```

I really recommend reading MDN's Web Docs about using fetch:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET', 
    body: JSON.stringify(yourData)
})
```